# Passing a word cloud choice to a corpus viewer

Tags: cloud, corpus, entity-linking

Can I pass a selected word (via a click) in a word cloud to the RedExp filter in a corpus viewer?
Is:
[image]

Desired:
[image]

ron_despain@hotmail.com...I'll join up next...Thanks for any help

Comment: It looks like I'll need a box in the Choice 1 widget to accept the selected words as well.  Maybe it can't be done.

Comment: I'm also not sure if this blog is for Orange3 only, so that's the app I'm asking about.